# google maps api javascript usage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-premium-plan

One of our project we are using   below mentioned google maps api

**Api1 :**
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + city ;

**API2:** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + currentLatLong.replace('\s', '')
            + "&destinations=" + destinationLatLong + "&mode=" + mode
            + "&language=en";

Previously we used to pass free key in parameter body .recently we enabled premium api and we got client id and Private crypto key .

Kindly advice how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation that explains how to use client ID and digital signature with Premium plan license

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#client-id

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#client-id

I believe the documentation is quite clear. You can also continue using an API key, but you must generate an API key in your Premium plan project.

If you don't know who has access to your Premium plan project, please reach out to technical support team as explained in

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support

Hope this helps!

Comment: Google is not recommending sign the url in JS. Can i generate a key and use that instead of ClientID

Comment: Yes you can. Premium plan supports both authentication methods: API key or client ID. https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#authentication-and-authorization You just need access to your Premium plan project in developer console.