# Google API key Vs. Google Client ID

Tags: google-maps

One of our customers is using google maps with a "Client ID". We've developed our product using the Google API Key. All of the features of the map are working properly using the API key, but we are unable to confirm that the client will get the same results with the  Client ID since we do not have one. Two question, do you believe that the features will work the same using either the API or the Client ID? Second question, how much does it cost to purchase a Client ID?

Answer (score 5):

Client IDs and API Keys are forms of authentication and authorization. There are easy-to-follow guidelines on their proper usage and their limits. Everything you need to know about them can be found in the documentation (also try seeing the docs per product in the 'For more information' section):

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#authentication_and_authorization

Related SO post and answer about using Client IDs for their Javascript API:
[google maps api javascript usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951389/google-maps-api-javascript-usage)

For pricing, read more about it here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

EDIT: There has been [recent Google Maps Platform pricing and product changes](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates.) You'll always need an API key and a [valid billing account associated to your Project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project) if you want to use the Google Maps Platform APIs. If you've never had a Client ID then you don't need to worry about it, just continue using your API keys.

You may run into some APIs (i.e. [Speed Limits API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits))  that seem to need a Premium Plan account. If you really need access to these, simply [contact sales using this form.](https://enterprise.google.com/maps/contact-form/)

P.S.
When using API keys, be sure to [properly restrict them!](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)